# Is there a modulo equivalent for (<) in functions?

Tags: f#

For example; the following line

```
    |> Seq.filter(fun i -> i < 123)
```

is the same thing as

```
    |> Seq.filter((<) 123)
```

Is there such a thing for the modulo operator? I'm not sure what the 2nd variant is, and can't find it referenced in the documentation either, so it makes searching somewhat difficult. So for bonus points, please tell me what this operator is called! :)

Currently using:

```
|> Seq.filter (fun i -> i % 2 = 0)
```

Looking for something like:

```
|> Seq.filter ((%) 2 = 0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first example is incorrect in saying that `fun i -> i < 123` is equal to `((<) 123)`. That is actually equivalent to `fun i -> 123 < i`. Let me explain, every operator is just a function but infix rather than prefix. As an example

```fs
let (+) x y = x + y
let add x y = x + y

let (-) a b = a - b // notice that the first argument (a) is on the left side of the operator
let subs a b = a - b
```

knowing this, we can then reason about `%` and `<` the same way

```
let (%) x y = x % y
let (<) x y = x < y

// therefore
fun i -> i < 123

// is equivalent to
fun i -> (<) i 123

// and mathematically equiv to 
((>=) 123)

// same with %
fun i -> i % 2

// is equiv to
fun i -> (%) i 2

// thus cant be reduced to eliminate the lambda
```

Comment: Oh shit, you're right, just realized I broke my existing code when I reduced that lambda.

Comment: @anthonytimmers Just never partial apply operators. It's just more confusing then helping in F#.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative, if you're dead-set on not writing out the lambda, is to lift it into a function:

```
let inline isEven x = x % 2 = 0

...

|> Seq.filter isEven
```

Comment: And that reads better.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, you are out of luck, because for partial application to be suitable, you need to swap both arguments of the `mod` operator. The lambda function is way more concise when taking into account that you are applying two operators, which requires function composition.

```
let flip f a b = f b a
{0..9}
|> Seq.filter ((flip (%) 2) >> ((=) 0))
|> (Seq.map string >> String.concat ", ")
// val it : string = "0, 2, 4, 6, 8"
```

Comment: Ah, "Partial Application" is the term, thank you, gonna read up on it further.

Comment: You really think `((flip (%) 2) >> ((=) 0))` is better than `(fun i -> i % 2 = 0)`? Or is this just an answer to the question?